# C# iterate through 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays

I the following array:
[image]

And I need to output the values as follows:

```
"API Docs Portal : op-api-docs"
"Big Ideas : op-bigideas"
"Education : op-education"
....
```

I've tried something but it doesn't works as expected...

```
        for (var x = 1; x <= reportValue.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (var y = 1; y <= reportValue.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                if (reportValue[x, y] != null)
                {
                    var id = reportValue[x, y];
                    var name = reportValue[x, y + 1];
                    var result = name + " : " + id;
                }
            }
        }
```

Note:
This is how I get the `reportValue` array (using C# Interop):

```
    var reportLast = ws.Range["A" + ws.Rows.Count].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
    var rngReport = (Excel.Range)ws.Range[ws.Cells[2, 1], ws.Cells[reportLast, 2]];
    var reportValue = rngReport.Cells.Value;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a 2d-array? Because usually indices start at `0`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Usually, yes - but they certainly don't have to. If you look at the debugger screenshot, this does indeed appear to be 1-based.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think so... it starts with 1 because I'm using C# Interop to get the values from an Excel Worksheet

Comment: " it doesn't works as expected..." doesn't tell us either what you expected, or what happened. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is your output/error?

Comment: Your use of `reportValue[x, y + 1]` looks pretty suspicious to me...

Comment: Adding the response of my code right now

Comment: The 2nd loop is unnecessary, and in fact will read off the end of the array

Comment: As it's not clear what your variable types are, I would avoid the use of 'var' and use the specific type instead when declaring your variables.

Comment: @T_Bacon is it a difference between declaring a string as `var` instead of `String`?

Comment: Specifically this line: `var reportValue = rngReport.Cells.Value;` It is not clear what the return type of `Value` is.

Comment: Hmm..ok, I'll read more about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear why you've got two loops here. You always want the same two elements for each row - index 1 and index 2. So you just need:

```
for (var x = 1; x <= reportValue.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    var id = reportValue[x, 1];
    var name = reportValue[x, 2];
    var result = name + " : " + id;
    // Use result
}
```

That will fetch `[1, 1] : [1, 2]`, then `[2, 1] : [2, 2]`, then `[3, 1] : [3, 2]` etc - which looks like it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need! It seems that the array is 1d...is this correct?

Comment: There are 2 dimensions to the array, but the "2nd dimension" is merely a key-value pair, it has a fixed length of 2. So you only need to iterate over the the "1st dimension" which seems to be of variable length...  Not sure that makes sense to anyone besides myself...

Answer (score 0):

Best way for transform 2D array to string in this format is:

```
var results = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array.Select(x => string.Join(" : ", x)));
```

For this array as example:

```
var array = new string[][]
{
    new string[] { "Hello world", "Hello" },
    new string[] { "Stack", "Overflow" }
};
```

Output for 'results' is:

> Hello world : Hello
>
> Stack : Overflow

Answer (score 0):

The title is somewhat misleading as it doesn't appear to be a standard 2D array.

Nevertheless:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= reportValue.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    string id = (string)reportValue[i, 1];
    string name = (string)reportValue[i, 2];
    builder.AppendLine(id + " : " + name);
}
// Process the result
```

This begins a `for` loop at 1 as the array appears to be 1-based as opposed to 0-based.

Assuming that there is only two values that you require, you can use [i, 1] and [i, 2] rather than looping through the length of the secondary part using `GetLength(1)`.